# How to implement ER Relationships :One to one, One To Many, Many to Many in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Perhaps, this could seem like the basics of database design.But,certainly i find these concepts a lil tricky in the sense that how they relate to each other.

Theory as per my understanding.

One to One :
When each particular entity has one record.

One to Many :
When each particular entity has many record

Many to Many :

Multiple entities have multiple records.

As per the above if i could relate an example as

1. ONE TO ONE

Each employee having a unique passport number.

Table Employee

```
Empid(pk) 
empname 
passpordid(fk to passport)
```

Table passport

```
passportid(pk) 
passportno
```

2. ONE TO MANY

An organisation having multiple employees

TABLE ORGANISATION

```
ORGID (PK) 
ORGNAME
EMPID (FK TO EMPLOYEE)
```

TABLE EMPLOYEE

```
EMPID (PK) 
EMPNAME
SALARY
```

This is the part that i want to know more that is `many to many`. I mean if we see one to many here. As a whole it could be said as many to many as many organisations having many employees but does that mean the whole relationship is many to many not one to many or one to many is a subset of many to many in the above example.

I wanna know the difference mainly between one to many and many to many both theoritically and by implementation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a many-to-many relationship would be EMPLOYEES and SKILLS, where SKILLS are things like "SQL", "Javascript", "Management" etc.  An employee may have many skills (e.g. may know SQL **and** Javascript), and a particular skill by be possessed by many employees (e.g. Jack and Jill **both** know SQL).

In a database like Oracle, you need a third table to express the many-to-many relationship between EMPLOYEES and SKILLS:

```
create table EMPLOYEE_SKILLS
  ( empid references EMPLOYEES
  , skillid references SKILLS
  , constraint EMPLOYEE_SKILLS_PK primary key (empid, skillid)
  );
```

Note that this third table has a foreign key to both of the other tables.

The table can also hold further information about the relationship - for example:

```
create table EMPLOYEE_SKILLS
  ( empid references EMPLOYEES
  , skillid references SKILLS
  , rating number
  , date_certified date
  , constraint EMPLOYEE_SKILLS_PK primary key (empid, skillid)
  );
```

Comment: if E1 has Sql, java and sql has E1, E2 does it mean its many to many.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja `EMPLOYEES` and `SKILLS` have the many to many relationship, because it it possible for an employee to have many skills, and for a skill to apply to many employees. To model that in a database, you can't put a `skillid` column on the `EMPLOYEES` table, and you can't put an `empid` column on the `SKILLS` table.

Comment: Yeah i get it now coz to be able to have both way relationship u need two foreign keys in terms of database hence one extra table to have many to many

Answer (score 0):

This is more a theory question that a programming one, but why not.

You could imagine a "many to many" as 1 table being a list of employees, and another table being a list of products sold.

Each employee is likely to "handle" more than 1 product, and each product could very well be handled by multiple employees, and it's quite possible that products A and B can be handled by, at the same time, employees C and D.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the basic idea of one-to-one and one-to many down, in theory.

One-to-one: each item A has a separate and unique item B

In a database, you could include the new data in the same table.  You could put it in a separate table, and enforce the one-to-one constraint by making the id into the remote table "unique" (indexing constraint), forcing the id for item B to not be repeated in the table.  In your example, this would be a constraint added to the passportid.

One to many: each item A has some number of item Bs

In a database, you put the key in the table on the "many" side.  So many Bs would have the same foreign key into table A.  In your example, put an orgid as a foireign key into the employee table.  Many employees can then point to a single organization, and an employee can belong to one organization.

Many to many: some number of As can be linked to any number of Bs and vice-versa

In a database, this is usually implemented as a link table, having just the IDs from both A and B.  Following you example, consider that an employee can be part of multiple groups (or projects), multitasking across those groups.  You could have a group table:

GROUPID (PK)
GROUPNAME

And the link table would then look like

LINKID (PK)
EMPID (FK TO EMPLOYEE)
GROUPID (FK TO GROUP)

This lets any employee be part of any number of groups, and groups to have any number of employees, AKA many-to-many.

A side comment:

Technically, you don't HAVE to have a LINKID in the link table.  But it makes it easier to manage the data in that table, and is generally considered "best practice".

Comment: Your answer is somewhere around what i am thinking too but not exactly the same.

Comment: Unclear what your comment means.  Your one-to-many example in your question won't work as is.  Maybe I wasn't clear that that was a problem.  What you have would allow many orgs to one employee.  The connection needs to come from the employee back to the orgs so you can have many employees to one org.  For many-to-many, I've done this link table concept many, many (ha!) times.  So regardless of what you were expecting, I think the info here is what you need.